# RxJS Queue Scheduler

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

My requirement is every 10 seconds, need to fetch data from Back end and update the properties for list of input. Also, request should hit the back end one by one. I have searched in the net and found that queue scheduler will be useful for this. (Let me know if my understanding is wrong). So i created the following code:

1. Starting interval for every 10 seconds

```
      private initializeInterval() {
        interval(10000).subscribe(x => {
          this.queueItems();
        });
      }
```

2. Creating Queue Scheduler:

```
  private queueItems() {
    let taskEntry: = ['111','2222','333']
    console.log("Started adding item in queue");
    taskEntry.forEach(item => {
      queue.schedule(this.retrieveData.bind(this), 100, item);
    })

    console.log("Completed adding item in queue");
  }
```

3. Retrieving data from backend

```
  private async retrieveData(item) {
    console.log("Starting");
    let result = await this.rest.downloadPrope(item);
    console.log(result)
    console.log("Completed");
  }
```

My Expectation is QueueScheduler calls retrieveData after completing the previous request...But all the request landing into retrieveData simultaneously.

My Output is:

Started adding item in queue

Completed adding item in queue

**Starting (3 times)** (Before getting Completed, next request landed from the queue)

Started adding item in queue

Completed adding item in queue

**Starting (3 times)**

completed (3 times)

completed (3 times)

Could you please tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue scheduler won't wait for the result of the tasks you put in.

It just defers the tasks you give it to the JavaScript event queue. You can't make it sequentially complete asynchronous tasks by using `async / await`.

What you probably want is the `concat` operator. You give it a list of observables that are subscribed to **one after the other**. This means, as soon as the first observable has completed, the second observable will be subscribed to.

Basically, create a list of your observables and then concat them like this:

`concat(['111','2222','333'].map(item => this.rest.downloadPrope(item)))`

This will download the three resources one after another.